# transform pandas data-frame grouping records on one col and counting frequencies of few other cols and making them as new cols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have this data-frame below:

```
userid    concessions    reason    contact    date
     1              0    aaa       call
     1              0    aaa       chat
     1              1    bbb       call       01-01-1990
     1              0    ccc       mail
     1              1    aaa       call       31-12-1992
     1              1    ccc       call       15-06-1994
     2              0    aaa       call
     2              0    aaa       chat
     3              1    bbb       chat       01-05-1990
     3              0    ccc       mail
     3              1    aaa       mail       10-02-1991
     3              1    ccc       call       21-08-1995
```

I would want to transform this data-frame to something like this:

```
userid    concessions    aaa    bbb    ccc    call    chat    mail    date
     1              3      3      1      2       4       1       1    15-06-1994
     2              0      2      0      0       1       1       0
     3              3      1      1      2       1       1       2    21-08-1995
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried using `groupby()` and `value_counts()`. It is giving me the frequency alright, but I am not quite sure how to transform the data-frame itself. I am quite new to pandas, and python as well, in general.

Edit:
I think I have not completely explained in my rush of thoughts while posting.

So, basically, I want to count the number of `concessions` for a `userid` and count the number of types of `reason` and `contact` appear for that `userid` and pick the latest `date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do some aggregations

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
pd.concat([
    df.groupby('userid').agg({'concessions': 'sum', 'date': 'max'}),
    pd.crosstab(df['userid'], df['reason']),
    pd.crosstab(df['userid'], df['contact'])
], axis=1)
```

---

```
        concessions       date  aaa  bbb  ccc  call  chat  mail
userid                                                         
1                 3 1994-06-15    3    1    2     4     1     1
2                 0        NaT    2    0    0     1     1     0
3                 3 1995-08-21    1    1    2     1     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed example

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

# Pivot the DataFrame and get the sums of 'concessions' by user
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='userid', values='concessions', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

# Usar groupby para contar las razones y contactos por usuario
reason_counts = df.groupby(['userid', 'reason']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
contact_counts = df.groupby(['userid', 'contact']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

# Obtain the maximum date per user
max_dates = df.groupby('userid')['date'].max()

# Combine results in a single DataFrame
result = pd.concat([pivot_table, reason_counts, contact_counts, max_dates], axis=1)
result.columns.name = None
result.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Rename columns according to specification
result.rename(columns={'aaa': 'concessions_aaa', 'bbb': 'concessions_bbb', 'ccc': 'concessions_ccc'}, inplace=True)

# Print
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code create the expected result.

```
# Step 1: Sum concessions
df_concessions = df.groupby('userid')['concessions'].sum().reset_index()

# Step 2: Count reasons
df_reason = df.pivot_table(index='userid', columns='reason', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0).reset_index()

# Step 3: Count contacts
df_contact = df.pivot_table(index='userid', columns='contact', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0).reset_index()

# Step 4: Get latest date
df_date = df.groupby('userid')['date'].max().reset_index()

# Merge all the DataFrames together
df_final = df_concessions.merge(df_reason, on='userid').merge(df_contact, on='userid').merge(df_date, on='userid')
```